# Method to extract details from YouTube Clip

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been looking for a method to extract details from a YouTube clip when only knowing the clip URL within a python script. I specifically need the original channel name.

The YouTube API does not seem to include any method to do so, only to extract details from a known *video* ID.

For example, this clip: https://www.youtube.com/clip/UgkxnEqNDtOHMOOoS5TyJFr2QOjdKbaTOTlW, with the ID `UgkxnEqNDtOHMOOoS5TyJFr2QOjdKbaTOTlW` is from this video https://youtu.be/z-e2bDx7tUA, with the ID `z-e2bDx7tUA`.

`z-e2bDx7tUA` *is* searchable with the API, but `UgkxnEqNDtOHMOOoS5TyJFr2QOjdKbaTOTlW` is not.

Even if there's a more roundabout method, such as getting the clip ID, then getting the video ID and then being able to use that within the API  would work. But I've not found an efficient way of doing so, including web scraping.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/9ea46f8a389ba3ca9b667d02b08ea26558d3d9c5/videos.php#L149) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by using https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=id&clipId=CLIP_ID you'll get in `item['videoId']` the video id associated with the clip.

For example the `CLIP_ID` [`UgkxfiAGoXJYA02_JdIzA3k3pvqpLNm90DBx`](https://www.youtube.com/clip/UgkxfiAGoXJYA02_JdIzA3k3pvqpLNm90DBx) is extracted from the `videoId` [`9bZkp7q19f0`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0).

Comment: My god, this is exactly what I've been looking for! Such a shame this isn't baked into YouTube's API directly.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of YouTube clips from a user?

Comment: AFAIK no, YouTube doesn't give the ability to list the clips of another user.